# How to create button to take action like TextInputAction.done

Tags: flutter

If I set Textfield>TextInputAction.Newline then, is it possible to creat a button that when user press and it will take the action like press done-button(TextInputAction.done , or .go , .search)?

Comment: do you mean like a RaisedButton on the UI or a special keyboard button

Comment: I mean the function as special keyboard button